# Custom resolver is ignored when trying to serialize an Exception

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'd like to serialize an `Exception` using a custom resolver.

Here's an example custom resolver - which should serialize only specified properties:

```
public class IncludeSpecifiedPropsResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    string[] propsToSerialize = null;
    public IncludeSpecifiedPropsResolver(params string[] propsToSerialize)
    {
        this.propsToSerialize = propsToSerialize;
    }
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var allProps = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        if (propsToSerialize == null || propsToSerialize.Length == 0)
        {
           return allProps;
        }
        return allProps.Where(p => propsToSerialize.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
string test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Exception("Something went wrong"), new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new IncludeSpecifiedPropsResolver("Message")
});
```

However, `CreateProperties` is ignored.

What else is missing so that the custom resolver would work as expected?

Comment: Did you place a break point? When you say "ignored" does it mean it never gets called?

Comment: Also have you tried to assign a value to the Message property like new Exception("Some cool message")?

Comment: @Darkonekt, yes (for both comments).

Comment: Where did you place your break point? in the first bracket of the CreateProperties method?

Comment: @Darkonekt, yes

Comment: Is this a .NET Core app? Also what version of Newtonsoft Json are you using?

Comment: @Darkonekt, not .Net Core, version 6.0.8, but I'm not sure it's version related. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Exception` implements the [`ISerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=netframework-4.8) interface, which has special handling in the `DefaultContractResolver`: the code path does not go through `CreateProperties()`.  You can override this behavior by setting the [`IgnoreSerializableInterface`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableInterface.htm) property to `true` in the constructor of your resolver.  If you do this, your code will work as intended.

```
public IncludeSpecifiedPropsResolver(params string[] propsToSerialize)
{
    this.propsToSerialize = propsToSerialize;
    IgnoreSerializableInterface = true;
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DNhwaH